# Problem assigning 'doJavaScript' return value to a variable (array)

Tags: javascript-automation

I'm experimenting with JXA and trying to 'port' a small script, which parses track names from the web page. This script is currently working as Keyboard Maestro macro and is executed in current Safari window:

```
var trackBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("track tracklist_track_title");
var trackList = [];
for (var a of trackBlock) {
    trackList.push(a.innerText);
}
trackList.join("\n");
```

The problem is that my porting attempt works well in JXA if `doJavaScript` returns a single string (variable `trackName1` contains track title):

```
var sfr = Application("Safari");
var trackName1 = sfr.doJavaScript('document.getElementsByClassName("track tracklist_track_title")[1].innerText', { in: sfr.windows[0].currentTab });
trackName1 // contains track name
```

But if I change the code, so that `doJavaScript` returns an array (as it was in the initial code), the variable is null. Can you, please, explain me: what am I doing wrong?

```
var sfr = Application("Safari");
var trackBlock = sfr.doJavaScript('document.getElementsByClassName("track tracklist_track_title")', { in: sfr.windows[0].currentTab });
trackBlock[0].innerText; // null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this statement:

```js
trackList.join("\n");
```

When you put that code in a JXA script, you need to escape the `\n`:

```js
trackList.join("\\n");
```

Here's my script that works:

```js
'use strict';

(function myMain() {  // function will auto-run when script is executed

var app = Application.currentApplication();
app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

/*
HOW TO USE:
 1. Open Safari to this URL:
     https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/
 2. Run this script
*/

var jsStr = `
(function myMain2() {
//debugger;

//return 'Just testing';

var elemCol = document.querySelectorAll('div.category-text-title');
var elemArr = Array.from(elemCol);
var titleArr = elemArr.map(e => {return e.innerText});

return titleArr.join('\\n');

})();
`

var safariApp = Application("Safari");
var oTab   = safariApp.windows[0].currentTab();
var pageURL  = oTab.url();
var pageTitle = oTab.name();

var jsScriptResults = safariApp.doJavaScript(jsStr, {in: oTab})

console.log(jsScriptResults);

return jsScriptResults;

})();

//-->RETURNS:
/* Questions & Suggestions

Macro Library

Plug In Actions

Tips & Tutorials

Wiki

Announcements

Status Menu Icons

Forum Admin
 */
```

Comment: Hello, JMichaelTX. Thanks for trying to help (and for many other useful posts here and in the KM forum)! There is nothing to do with escaping '\n' in my example. Im posting a revised version of my question below. Can you, please, take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more clear example of the issue. Here is the code:

```
var sfr = Application("Safari");
var scr2run = 'document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")';
var scr2run1 = 'document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")[0]';
var scr2run2 = 'document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")[0].innerText';

var trackName = sfr.doJavaScript(scr2run, { in: sfr.windows[0].currentTab });
var trackName1 = sfr.doJavaScript(scr2run1, { in: sfr.windows[0].currentTab });
var trackName2 = sfr.doJavaScript(scr2run2, { in: sfr.windows[0].currentTab });
```

Here is the output:

```
app = Application("Safari")
    app.doJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"tracklist_track_title\")", {in:app.windows.at(0).currentTab})
        --> null
    app.doJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"tracklist_track_title\")[0]", {in:app.windows.at(0).currentTab})
        --> null
    app.doJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"tracklist_track_title\")[0].innerText", {in:app.windows.at(0).currentTab})
        --> "From What Is Said To When It's Read"
```

Why the two first `doJavaScript` calls return `null`, but the third one returns expected value?

Comment: The first one returns an array, the second returns an HTMLCollection, the third returns a string. My guess is that doJavaScript only handles strings as return values. osascript (whether the JavaScript or AppleScript flavor) wouldn't know what to do with an HTMLCollection anyway. Convert your result to a string to pass it back.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the first `getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection and the second returns a single Node object.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question:

> Why the two first doJavaScript calls return null, but the third one
>   returns expected value?

```js
var scr2run = 'document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")';
var scr2run1 = 'document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")[0]';
var scr2run2 = 'document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")[0].innerText';
```

The third JavaScript returns a text value, whereas the first two do not.  They return an element collection and an element.